# Trying to get a cell stack to display data from an array separate from the activating array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently, when I click a cell in the top boxes, the bottom set (e85) uses `=filter(e74:e83, len(e74:e83), "")` to pull the data down and stack it, automatically bumping them up to the top of the column so there are no spaces.

[empty sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpnex.png)

[filled sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJE16.png)

I'd like the bottom box to use the same formula/array, but I would like the bottom cells to display the correlating information on the right, i.e., when box "M24/T?" is activated, "M24-TPK-35B" displays in the bottom cells.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

I've tried tons of functions like `IFS`, `IF(COUNTIF`, and the one that works the closest is `=FILTER(E74:E83, LEN(E74:E83), "")`, it just doesn't display the data i need it to.

Comment: Do you mean that the result is correct except instead of `M24/T?` it should display `M24-TPK-35B`? If not, please explain in more detail.

Comment: yes ^, the formula does what I want it to, but I don't know how to incorporate the data from the table on the right into the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A 'Replaced' Filter

```
=LET(datal,E74:E83,datar,T74:T82,dell,"/",delr,"-",
    dl,FILTER(datal,LEN(datal),""),
    IFNA(XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(dl,dell),
        TEXTBEFORE(datar,delr),datar),dl))
```

[image]