# Trying to get names from a box on the right to automatically appear in another box when a different box has a value in it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, let

hope the title wasn't too confusing.

this is my project:

[image: teams]

I'm trying to figure out how to get the names on the right (NICK-GL) to stack on top of each other at the bottom, when one of the mon-fri boxes has one of the correlating names in it, i.e., when Nick is is displayed in F3, NICK-GL appears in F21. The names on the right will change from week to week. I'd like them to automatically bump to the top of the list at the bottom but stay in the order they are on the Name list.

If you already couldn't tell, I'm a beginner.

I found this formula on stackoverflow, but I don't know how to implement it into my sheet.

```
=LET(datal,E74:E83,datar,T74:T82,dell,"/",delr,"-",
    dl,FILTER(datal,LEN(datal),""),
    IFNA(XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(dl,dell),
        TEXTBEFORE(datar,delr),datar),dl))
```

If someone could also explain to me what each part of that means, I would tremendously appreciate it.

Comment: Duplicate Post : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142988/trying-to-get-a-cell-stack-to-display-data-from-an-array-separate-from-the-activ)

Comment: When I try to use that code with my cells, it just says "spill"

Comment: Do you have any formula or data below the cells where you have entered the formula. The above formula is one single formula which will return as an array, so you dont have to fill down, it returns the output for the whole range.

Comment: Ah, yes. I deleted it, but now it's just listing all the names instead of the ones on the right.

Comment: Also to understand how the formula is working you can goto `Formulas` tab and click on `Evaluate` to understand it will show up the steps one by one, as there is no `LAMBDA()` involved it will be easy for you to understand as well

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try to figure this out and I'll report back, thanks!

Comment: You could have tried: `=LET(_Data, D3:D19,_Names, $K3:$K7,FILTER(_Names,1-ISNA(XMATCH(TEXTBEFORE(_Names,"-"),_Data))))` and fill right, so when there is some data in columns `E` to `J` it will populate.

Comment: welp, that worked perfect, thank you! im going o look up the isna and xmatch to better understand them. cheers!

Comment: Do you want me to post that as an answer with an explanation? ?

Comment: yes, please. if youre not too busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I have understood correctly, the following formula should work as per the given conditions:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C21</kbd>

```
=LET(_Data, C3:C19,_Names, $J3:$J7,FILTER(_Names,1-ISNA(XMATCH(TEXTBEFORE(_Names,"-"),_Data)),""))
```

---

- The above formula is dynamic array formula which uses firstly the `LET()` function, which helps in eliminating redundant calculations, avoids using repeated formulas/ranges and improves working functionalities of Excel by performance.
- `_Data` variable is the source range, in the below example it starts from `C3:C19` (It might be different in your data, needs to suit as per your data, also don't use merged cells, instead use center across selection if its needed for formatting or designing, still its better to avoid, and use single cell only).
- `_Names` variable is the range on which the following function will be using as `lookup_value` and return the same one which matched as an output. `J3:J7` (again change range as per your suit).
- Using `TEXTBEFORE()` function extracting the names so that it can be used as a `lookup_value` to match with the original source and return the positions of the respective names as per the source data.
- The above is used within `XMATCH()` to return the positions as mentioned above, and when not matched it will return as `#N/A` hence instead of using `ISNUMBER()` which can also be used, but used `ISNA()` which returns `TRUE` for errors while for numbers returns as `FALSE` reversing them by using `1-`
- Using `FILTER()` function now returning the output for those which are only `TRUE` values. and when there is nothing matched or if there is no data it will use the last param of the `FILTER()` and return as empty `""`(in screenshot its not shown, formula shows that)

---

There is another shorter way of doing this is taking the advantage of `COUNTIFS()` or `COUNTIF()` function:

```
=LET(
     _Data, C3:C19,
     _Names, $J3:$J7,
     FILTER(_Names,COUNTIF(_Data,TEXTBEFORE(_Names,"-"))))
```

---

Using One Single Dynamic Array Formula to return the output:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, C3:I19,
     _Name, J3:J7,
     _Rows, ROWS(_Name),
     _Colums, COLUMNS(_Data),
     IFERROR(MAKEARRAY(_Rows,_Colums,LAMBDA(r,c,
     INDEX(FILTER(_Name,1-ISNA(XMATCH(TEXTBEFORE(_Name,"-"),
     INDEX(_Data,,c))),""),r))),""))
```

---

Comment: Actually, I was curious to see the formula is really working or not, I found it doesnt as mentioned in comments above by you, as well as the one you have come up it also returns false positives, hence i tried these ones. I will try to update with more better formulas with one single dynamic array.

Comment: @Guy I have also updated with one single DAF, hence one don't need to fill right!

Comment: awesome, i noticed you used lambda in it, nice :)

Answer (score 1):

So the  `LET function` lets you name and 'stack' calculations/variables; I'll break it down for you:

```
=LET(datal,E74:E83,
    datar,T74:T82,
    dell,"/",
    delr,"-",
    dl,FILTER(datal,LEN(datal),""),
   IFNA(XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(dl,dell),TEXTBEFORE(datar,delr),datar),dl))
```

`datal,E74:E83` selects the range E74 to E83, and calls it 'datal';

`datar,T74:T82` does the same for range T74 to T82, and calls it 'datar';

`dell` is a variable later used to put in "/";

`delr` does the same but with "-";

`dl,FILTER(datal,LEN(datal),"")` filters the 'datal', based on the lenght of text string in the selected range, or outputs nothing ("") if nothing is found; -I'm not exactly sure how the LEN function is used to filter data-

finally we have the calculation part of the formula: `IFNA(XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(dl,dell),TEXTBEFORE(datar,delr),datar),dl))`

IFNA wraps the formula, it's a variaton of IFERROR; when the included formula returns NA error, it then will output 'dl'.

XLOOKUP will search for the 'dl' variable (which we named above), but with only a part of that data: the TEXTBEFORE is used on text, but before a delimeter (dell, or "/"); in 'datar', but again only partially, this time with the text before the "-" (delr).

Then XLOOKUP returns from 'datar'.

I'm assuming you know a bit about XLOOKUP here.

Hope you learn something from it, if something is still unclear, don't hesitate to ask for help. Hopefully I or someone else can bring some more clarification.

Comment: great information, thank you! that cleared a lot up. So far I've got it down to:                                  =LET(datal,D3:D19,datar,K3:K7,
    dl,FILTER(datal,LEN(datal),""),
    IFNA(XLOOKUP(datar, datar,datar),dl))